# Smart way for 2 out 3 raced redux-saga effects having the same follow up flow

Tags: javascript, generator, redux-saga

I have 2 out of 3 effects racing against each other that should result in a refresh from the server if they win the race.

That's how I currently do that:

```
function* refreshItems() {
  while (true) {
    bool refreshFromServer = true
    const { nextRefresh, items } = yield call(fetchItems)
    const racer = {
      duration: call(delay, 60*1000),
      manual: take(REFRESH_ITEMS),
    }
    if (nextRefresh > 0) {
      racer.remote = call(delay, nextRefresh * 1000)
    }
    const { remote, manual, duration } = yield race(racer)
    refreshFromServer = remote || manual
    // alternative: refreshFromServer = !duration
  }
}
```

I wonder if there is a smarter way of facilitating the return result of the race?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way seems fine, but one thing you could do is compose races.  Something like (untested):

```
function* refreshItems() {
  while (true) {
    const { nextRefresh, items } = yield call(fetchItems)
    const refreshRace = {
      manual: take(REFRESH_ITEMS)
    }
    if (nextRefresh > 0) {
      refreshRace.remote = call(delay, nextRefresh * 1000)
    }
    const racer = {
      duration: call(delay, 60*1000),
      refresh: race(refreshRace),
    }
    const { refresh, duration } = yield race(racer)
    ... just use refresh, now
  }
}
```

btw, some other notes:

- your race of two delays seems slightly silly
- depending on what exactly you want, you could maybe use debounce?  or write something similar

Comment: Thanks. Does this really work with composition like that? I am using 2 delays because I want to prevent a server hit, if only a local timer needs to be updated (`duration`).

Comment: yes, I think it should compose, though it's not tested.  race is just an effect which waits for the first of some other effects to finish, then cancels the rest.  when race is canceled, it cancels all its racers.  so when one of the racers is a race, the proper thing should happen

RE duration:  is delay basically just setTimeout?  it seems like if nextRefresh < 60, you can safely refresh, and if greater, you can omit it from the race

Comment: Nice tip with the nextRefresh regarding to duration refresh. One little glitch in your answer though. `refreshRace`must also be a race. So `refresh: race(refreshRace)` Then it works.

Comment: whoops!  that was what i meant :) thanks for catching it.  I've edited it now

Comment: Thanks for your help! The idea to have another race in a race is nice :) I've also added ur suggestion to only race the remote `if (nextRefresh > 0 && nextRefresh <= 60000) {} else { add duration to race }`